# fabric js object transformMatrix roundingBox

Tags: matrix, transform, fabricjs

When I add an image in canvas and I do a transformMatrix to the image, the roundingBox is shifted.

Look my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ULsr4/2/

canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/archigraphs/lovely-bones/256/Tree-icon.png', function(img) {

```
img.transformMatrix = [1, 0, 0.7, 1, 0, 0];
canvas.add(img);
img.setCoords();
```

});

canvas.renderAll();

can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it still needed for you but try to use group object inside you fabric.Image.fromURL callback, ie:

```
var group = new fabric.Group([img], {
                                  left: 10,
                                  top: 10
                              });
canvas.add(group);
group.setCoords();
```